# Python 3.6.4 Discord Bot. Embedding an Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I need some help on how to embed a random image from a list.
This is what I have so far:

[image: 1]

As you can see I found:
`e.set_image(url=possible_responses)`
however I can't figure out how to use it even after googling it for a while.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import the random module.

```
import random
```

Then make a list with all the image urls in it.

```
all_image_choices = ["image1url", "image2url"]
```

Use `random.choice()` to choose a random item from the list.

```
chosen_image = random.choice(all_image_choices)
```

Set the url in `e.set_image` to the randomly chosen url.

Example:

```
chosen_image = random.choice(all_image_choices )
e = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc")
e.set_image(url=chosen_image)
await client.send_message(contex, embed=e)
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I noticed you didn't close the end bracket so I put that after embed=e but it says     await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=e)
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out. I've update my answer to use `context` rather than message because you are using it in a command. `message.channel` was for using it in a `on_message` which I now can see you are not using.

Comment: @SirFelisCatus Was this able to fix your problem?